# LineSeries AreaSeries on AreaChart, How do i get the intersection point?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am plotting an AreaSeries and a LineSeries on a AreaChart using Flex 3 in built chart components. I want to code a custom item renderer for LineSeries to be shown at the intersection points where LineSeries crosses AreaSeries.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to accomplish by simply adding another series.